# Why does my regex not work in iOS for quote marks?

Tags: javascript

```
var regExp = /[\{\}\[\]\/|~`^\+┼<>@\$&\‘\"\'\“\=]/gi;
```

When entering double and single quotation marks in the ios environment, regular expressions are not accepted.

Is there something wrong with my regular expression?

Example:

```
$(".chkspchar").keyup(function(){
                    var regExp = /[\{\}\[\]\/|~`^\+┼<>@\$&\‘\"\'\“\=]/gi;
                    var spaceExp = /\s{2,}/gi;
                    var ipt = this;
                    if(regExp.test($(ipt).val()) || spaceExp.test($(ipt).val())){
                        $(".chkspchar").blur();
                        UI.msg.alert("; : , . ? ! - _ ( ) * % # " ,function() {
                            var inputStr = $(ipt).val().substring(0, $(ipt).val().length-1);
                            $(ipt).val(inputStr);
                            UI.msg.close();
                        });

                    }
                });
```

Comment: I just tested that on iOS Safari. It returns `true` as expected.

Comment: Mac Firefox - result is `true`

Comment: (Side note: There's no need to escape most of the characters you have escaped in that expression, just ```/[{}\[\]\/|~`^+┼<>@$&‘"'“=]/gi``` would be fine [technically you don't even have to escape the `[`, but...].)

Comment: @Justinas - The OP specifies iOS, which uses a different JavaScript engine (JavaScriptCore) from Firefox on a Mac (SpiderMonkey).

Comment: In the ios keypad, the regular expression is not applied.

Comment: @김지성 - Nothing in your question connects the regular expression to anything. Where/how are you using it? But separately, you've clearly stated in your question that `regExp.test(test)` returns `false`. It doesn't.

Comment: Changed example. Is there something wrong with the function?

Comment: Did you forget `”` and `’` (closing quotes)?

Comment: where is the closing quote?